# Ansible fails with "Permission denied (keyboard-interactive)"

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have two different machines I can connect to in SSH, using a corporate VPN and proxy.

For that, my `~/.ssh/config` has two hosts defined like this:

```
Host foobar
  User alice
  HostName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ProxyCommand nc -x proxy-socks.foobar.com:4242 %h %p
```

The `ProxyCommand` is identical for both hosts, only the `HostName` and `User` are different. Each host has my public key, I can connect to each one simply by typing `ssh foobar`, no password is asked.

Now, I tried to use ansible to act on these machines. I have an `inventory.cfg` like that listing the name of both machines as defined in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
[vpn]
foobar
barfoo
```

I tried this simple command:

```
ansible -i inventory.cfg vpn -m ping
```

This worked for one of the machines, but not the other. Here is the redacted output:

```
foobar | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
barfoo | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Welcome on barfoo [...] Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Since I got the "welcome" message from the host in the output, it means that I did reach the host (so the proxy configuration should be ok).
But I cannot understand the error "Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).". I can connect to this machine by SSH without password (in fact, the admins even disabled password authentication, I had to send them my public key by e-mail).

I tried to explicitely specify my SSH key by adding `--private-key $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`, but the error message was exactly the same.

By curiosity, I tried with Python's package `fabric`, but this worked fine for both machines:

```
import fabric
fabric.Connection('barfoo').run('hostname')
```

So it seems there is something weird going on between ansible and this machine configuration. Any clue?

---

**EDIT**

Using the advice from @GeralexGR, I added `-vvvv` in my ansible command to have more output.

In the output, I could see that ansible is making this call to SSH :

```
ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/alice/.ansible/cp/dbd7338475"' barfoo '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
```

By trial and error, I could reduce this command to this one :

```
ssh -vvv -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey barfoo 'hostname'
```

This command *fails* on one machine but not the other. However, if I remove the `PreferredAuthentications` option, it works fine with both machines.

When it fails, it outputs something like that:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: [...]
[...]
debug1: Server accepts key: [...]
[...]
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

If I remove this option and do a simple `ssh -vvvv`, I get this in the output:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: [...]
[...]
debug1: Server accepts key: [...]
[...]
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
[...]
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
[...]
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
```

So, my guess is that `keyboard-interactive` is required for this machine. And indeed, if I put both `publickey` and `keyboard-interactive` in the option, this works:

```
ssh -vvv -o preferredauthentications=publickey,keyboard-interactive barfoo 'hostname'
```

So, back to ansible, I tried this:

```
ansible -vvvv --ssh-extra-args='-o preferredauthentications=publickey,keyboard-interactive' -i inventory.cfg -m ping vpn
```

But it still failed, I guess that this authentication mecanism is not possible with ansible? I am not sure why/how keyboard-interactive is needed here, since I am never prompted for a password. I will ask the admins of the machine.

Comment: Try again to install the keys of your working machine to barfoo machine. You can use `ssh-copy-id user@barfoo` . Make sure you use the user that you will try to connect and run ansible playbooks. For example if you use user1 on local machines, install certificates for user1 on barfoo computer. You can also use `ansible -m ping machines -vvvv to get a more detailed output`

Comment: @GeralexGR thank you, I managed to understand better the issue with this option (see my edit), but I am still stuck.

Comment: Your server is apparently requiring both a key and a password to connect. To provide the password you either set it in your inventory as `ansible_ssh_pass` or require the ansible command to ask for it interactively before starting connection with the `--ask-pass / -k` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was kindly given by @Zeitounator in comments.

I added these two lines in my `inventory.cfg` file (with a dummy password):

```
[vpn:vars]
ansible_ssh_pass=foo
```

Now the initial ansible command works well.

Alternatively, using the `--ask-pass` option on the command line works as well:

```
ansible --ask-pass -i inventory.cfg -m ping vpn
```

---

For the context I asked a bit more information to the admins of the machine. This machine does not ask me for a password or anything, however, it asks to some external users (not me) to accept some terms and conditions. This is why the `keyboard-interactive` mechanism is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Duo requires `keyboard-interactive` authentication, but ansible turned it off by `-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no` as seen from the `ansible -vvv` output as shown in the original post. I added `ssh_args -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=yes` in ansible.cfg:

```
ssh_args = -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey,keyboard-interactive -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=300s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=yes
```

and now it works fine.

Comment: This worked for me as well when trying to run ansible on an ec2 with google-authenticator mfa setup for ssh, ty!

Comment: I would like to introduce the above comment in the answer but the edit queue is full at the moment, as usual to me...

Comment: I also don't fully understand what "Duo requires" is so I'm inclined to replace that with "your server requires... " since that is the meaning I think. But indeed the edit queue is full now. Waiting to save.

Comment: "Duo" is an addon application providing Multi-Factor Authentication" (MFA), but your edit "your server requires" instead of "Due requires" is fine, which is more generic.